# How to retrieve variable declared in javascript script tag

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I have an html file in which i have set a variable called `flxweb_user` inside the script tag. In the same html i am using jinja. I need to check if this value for `flxweb_user` matches a specific value and so need to access this variable inside jinja if condition.

Sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">flxweb_user = somevalue;</script>
```

jinja if statement in which i need to check this value

```
{% if c.user.role.name == 'teacher'%} 
    <span>
        <a href="{{ config.webroot_url }}{{ item.getPermaHandle(include_version=False) }}" title="{{ item.display_label() }} for {{ book.title }}">{{ item.display_label() }}</a>
    </span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think you've greatly misunderstood how HTML and Javascript interact. The backend process building the HTML runs before the Javascript executes; it can't access anything from the Javascript. (On the other hand, if you've hardcoded the value into the template in the `<script>` tag, why can't you hardcode it into your Python code at the same time?)

Comment: I am not hardcoding the value in script tag. My bad that i wrote it in sample code. It is like flxweb_user = somevalue

Comment: Can you suggest any other alternative way through which i can access a cookie's value in my jinja code?

Comment: Jinja is a templating engine. That means it is a library that takes a document with special formatting and interprets it according to the values it is given when called by the master program to produce an output static document. It can only access values that are passed to him by the server software. Are you using the Flask framework?